# Why is this fan coil actuator missing a lever?

Tags: hvac, cooling

I live in a building where a lot of people have a hard time getting their units down to any acceptable temperature. We're all learning more about how fan coils work and one of the things that keeps coming up is the actuator.

One resident has been able to get cool air again by setting a lever on their actuator to the open position. Many others of us want to do this but find our actuators are without levers, even though the casing suggests there should be one.

**Actuator with lever (in closed position)**
[image: Actuator with lever (in closed position)]

**Actuator without lever**

[image: Actuator without lever]

My guess is the spring visible in the "without lever" picture would be compressed by the lever, if it existed.

**The question is, why would the actuator without a lever be missing it?**

Possibly related info - a local HVAC company makes $$$ from the building every year as several people will call them when they can't get cold air, they invariably replace the actuator which seems to "fix" the issue. Excuse the paranoia, but could missing levers on actuators be a way to increase callouts?

Comment: I would suggest hanging around while they're doing the work next time the HVAC company comes out. See what the new actuator looks like. Or, even better, just look for a name and model number on that one in the picture and see what it looks like when the manufacturer has finished making it. Must say, though, that if moving the lever to the left "fixes" the problem, the one without the lever is _all_ the way to the left...

Comment: Also, you "live in a building"... Is that a condo building where you each own your own place and are responsible for your own maintenance, or is it an apartment where someone else owns it and is responsible for all maintenance? If it's a condo, just hire a different HVAC company! If it's a rental, well, you're not out anything by the constant maintenance calls, except comfort and possible rent increases, but you've always got the "move out" option.

Comment: Try verification of the model you have some models don’t have all the options but the same frame I see this quite often in different equipment types.